# jupyter notebook cannot display properly in mobile browser

Tags: mobile, jupyter

I am trying to use my mobile phone to browse jupyter notebook.  However, the output display takes up only halve of the phone screen instead of using the entire width.  But markdown contents are all ok.  How could I fix this problem?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. did you try **desktop site** option in your smartphone's browser?
2. refer to this link: https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-open-ipynb-file-on-iOS-or-Android-devices

If it doesn't work, share the link of jupyter notebook so that it can be verified.